# How to connect Magento REST Api with OAuth Authentication in Android Application?

Tags: android, magento

Please Help me here i am searching from last two days but i didn't get the simple code for this.
I want to connect to My Magento Rest API using OAuth

Comment: can you  please post your code which you tried so far ? or you try to google for the same ?

Comment: @user1140237 i am new to this so i am just searching for it.So far i have not tried anything.